# How to retrieve hidden urls accessible through links stubbed out with ’#’

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, nokogiri, web-inspector

My application needs to scrape data from the WTA website: single rankings and single road rankings (from player ranked first to player ranked 1000th). Rankings are accessible through the following link: http://www.wtatennis.com/rankings

Just below the pictures portraying the first ranked players of the two single ranking categories, there is a menu for accessing all the ranking categories: single, doubles, porsche race singles, porsche race doubles. The problem is that clicking on these links the url in the address bar of the browser does not change. Web inspector shows that these links are all created with the same `<a>` tag with `href="#"`.

The http://www.wtatennis.com/rankings url shows by default the first 100 players of the single rankings, so I assume there should be a hidden url dedicated to the road rankings page. At first I thought about one single document organized with tabbed-navigation, but web inspector shows that they are all different pages.

Scrolling down the page to the bottom of the list, it is possible to notice that the players ranked above the 100th position are accessible via pagination. Pagination links are also stubbed out with `’#’`:

```
<a class="footable-page-link" href="#">1</a>
<a class="footable-page-link" href="#">2</a>
<a class="footable-page-link" href="#">3</a>
...
```

Thus, even the urls for information on players ranked above number 100 are hidden.

Is there any way to get access to all these hidden urls? 
I wrote a letter to the Vice President and General Counsel of the ATP and I got his permission to use those urls, but when I explicitly asked him with a second letter to be provided with such information, he responded that "those URLs are all publicly available on our website and the WTA website". Taking for granted that he has right on this, and he might have more important matters to do than having a private correspondence with me (I suspect a third letter would be annoying), I thought that I may simply lacking the knowledge to retrieve them from their websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, if you see

```
<a href="#">...</a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">...</a>
```

in a page, that means you're looking at a link controlled by JavaScript:  Clicks on that link are captured by an event listener, usually on the page or on an ancestor element, and the behavior of the "link" is to do whatever the JavaScript makes it do.

In the case of the page you're looking at, the data is loaded entirely through Ajax calls, initiated by the JavaScript:  The JS calls back to the server for the current page, and gets back a `scores.json` blob that it then uses to rebuild the table.  When you click on one of those pagination links, another Ajax call fires off, and the page gets rebuilt accordingly.  (You can observe the Ajax calls and their responses on the inspector's "Network" tab.)

So there are no links to other pages, and thus no "hidden URLs" for you to obtain:  There is only one page, and it is rebuilt with new data as you click around — a so-called "Single-Page Application" (SPA).

Comment: I understand. I suppose I have to give up on using Nokogiri to scrape content from a SPA.

Comment: Yes, anything that looks at just the HTML and ignores the JavaScript likely will not be able to make sense of very much of anything in a single-page application.